# Explain this SQL query in plain English

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

Please explain, in plain English, what question this SQL query answers:

```
SELECT SUM(price) FROM Room r, Hotel h

WHERE r.hotelNo = h.hotelNo and hotelName = 'Paris Hilton' and
roomNo NOT IN

(SELECT roomNo FROM Booking b, Hotel h
WHERE (dateFrom <= CURRENT_DATE AND
dateTo >= CURRENT_DATE) AND
b.hotelNo = h.hotelNo AND hotelName = 'Paris Hilton');
```

Comment: Why not? I think it makes sense. He wants to figure out what the query does, essentially, explain in plain English.

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed.  The question seems very straightforward.  What exactly was deemed ambiguous, vague or  incomplete about it?

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming you're asking what does that query do in plain English:

> How much would it cost to book all rooms at the "Paris Hilton" hotel that are vacant today?

Comment: thanks so much cpalmer..... and do you by any chance know how to evaluate this query by the DBMS?

Comment: Kevvinniveguy, "DBMS" means "DataBase Management System" which is a generic term to discuss any database. Which DBMS are you using specifically? MySQL, Microsoft SQL, Oracle? It will be a different process depending on which you're using.

Comment: If you are having trouble comprehending this statement, perhaps you need to go and read up on the basics of how relational databases work.  Specifically, in this order, history of databases, Entity Relational Diagrams, normalization, SQL features/drawbacks/uses/history, creating tables, doing simple selects, then joins, then summary queries, and, finally, sub-queries.  There's a lot of thought that has went into that statement and to fully comprehend it in a 550~ character comment is hard to do.

Comment: thanks...it says to get some points for voting

Comment: @Nitrodist wasn't aware there was a 550 char limit in 2010. Interesting. I Wonder in hindsight if this comment wasn't a tad rude. In total honesty, I agree. However, I wo

Answer (score 1):

This query appears to return the sum of the prices of all the rooms in the Paris Hilton hotel which aren't booked for today.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably supposed to represent the total price of rooms available as of today at the "Paris Hilton" hotel. Why they are filtering on both HotelNo and HotelName.

I guess the question would be:

> What is the total value of rooms
>   available as of today at the "Paris
>   Hilton" hotel?

Comment: This is the answer. However I suspect the business would really want to know is "how much money are we potentially not makiing today"

Answer (score 0):

question would be like,

find out list of room that are not booked so far till today in the hotel "Paris Hilton" and return the sum of that amount.